# Expanded TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a `TreeView` control and all the nodes populated from xml. The tree has 5 elements in the first level and each contains several elements in level 2. My requirmrnt is only first element should be `Expanded` when the startup of my application. I have written the method like this:

```
public void SelectAndExpand(ItemsControl ParentContainer)
    {
        TreeViewItem CurrentContainer = (TreeViewItem)ParentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
        if (CurrentContainer == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        CurrentContainer.IsExpanded = true;
        CurrentContainer.UpdateLayout();

        TreeViewItem ChildItem = (TreeViewItem)CurrentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
        if (ChildItem != null)
        {
            ChildItem.IsSelected = true;
            CurrentContainer.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```

and I called this method like this:

```
public Window1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectAndExpand(MyTree);
    }
```

But this doesn't work...

any suggestions to overcome this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `ItemContainerStyle` so that the items are expanded :

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  ...
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Thomas

I could overcome this problem by other way...

I set the Loaded event as

```
Loaded="MyTree_Loaded"
```

I handeld as

```
private void MyTree_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem CurrentContainer = (TreeViewItem)MyTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
        if (CurrentContainer == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        CurrentContainer.IsExpanded = true;
        CurrentContainer.UpdateLayout();

        TreeViewItem ChildItem = (TreeViewItem)CurrentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
        if (ChildItem != null)
        {
            ChildItem.IsSelected = true;
            CurrentContainer.UpdateLayout();                
        }            
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to follow this article [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx), and the load the xml to the ViewModel classes.

You can set the IsExpanded property directly in the codebehind without interacting with the TreeView.